# Apache reverse proxy configuration (/context to /)

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, redirect, proxypass

I'm having this issue trying to proxy a site to another context on a different domain

**What I currently have ?**

I have a fully functional web site running on the following URL:

https://helloworld.domainone.com/

Note: my site runs on the root of that domain.

**What I want?**

I want to write a proxy that can redirect successfully the following:

```
https://domaintwo.com/me/helloworld/     ====>     https://helloworld.domainone.com/
```

**How I'm trying to achieve it?**

I have an Apache proxy like this:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/me/(.*)/(.*)$"     "https://$1.domainone.com/$2"
ProxyPassReverse "^/me/(.*)/(.*)$"   "https://$1.domainone.com/$2"
```

**The Problem ?**

When I try with my first site *'helloworld'* (I'm using a regex because I have multiple) I get redirected correctly but the browser fails to locate some resources because the site is telling to look for those at the root of the domain, **and I can't change that fact**, for example:

```
https://domaintwo.com/polyfills.2ae2103bb74c46d7.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with ...
```

and of course, for this to work, that should be:

```
https://domaintwo.com/me/helloworld/polyfills.2ae2103bb74c46d7.js
```

I'll appreciate any ideas,

Comment: Shouldn't it be, ProxyPassMatch "^/me/(.*)/(.*)$"     "https://$1.domainone.com/$2" ?

Comment: Thanks, yes my bad, however, just for your knowledge, that does not solve the issue